# How to store the captured image from the camera into external sd card and then load it using another button into a grid?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-camera-intent, android-external-storage

@Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new             Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivity(intent);

When the following code is executed a camera screen appears and nothing happens when captured button is clicked.I want to store that captured image into sdcard.

Comment: startActivityForResult and check the result, the intent bag will have the URI you want to display

Comment: `I want to store that captured image into sdcard.` You? Wrong. Let the camera app do it directly. Use EXTRA_OUTPUT.